# Removing values from particular cells and adjusting the values in the rows accordingly

Tags: r

I want to remove a particular value, i.e."cap" in the example, from all the cells containing that value and shift the next value in that row to that cell where that value "cap" first appeared. This also changes the values in the "OrderNumber" columns respectively.

This will help in generating the example:

```
custID <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5))
OrderNumber_1 <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1))
OrderNumber_2 <- data.frame(c(2, NA , 2,2,2))
OrderNumber_3 <- data.frame(c(3, NA, 3, 3, NA))
OrderNumber_4 <- data.frame(c(4, NA, 4, 4, NA))
OrderNumber_5 <- data.frame(c(5, NA, 5, 5, NA))
OrderType_1 <- data.frame(c("ball", "pen", "ball", "shuttle", "pen"))
OrderType_2 <- data.frame(c("pen", NA, "cap", "cap", "pen"))
OrderType_3 <- data.frame(c("cap", NA, "cap", "cap", NA))
OrderType_4 <- data.frame(c("shuttle", NA, "ball", "cap", NA))
OrderType_5 <- data.frame(c("pen", NA, "cap", "ball", NA))

report <- cbind(custID, OrderNumber_1, OrderNumber_2, OrderNumber_3, OrderNumber_4, OrderNumber_5, OrderType_1, OrderType_2, OrderType_3, OrderType_4, OrderType_5 )

report <-as.data.frame(report)
```

expected result can be produced by the following code:

```
custID <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5))
OrderNumber_1 <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1))
OrderNumber_2 <- data.frame(c(2, NA , 2,2,2))
OrderNumber_3 <- data.frame(c(3, NA, NA, NA, NA))
OrderNumber_4 <- data.frame(c(4, NA, NA, NA, NA))
OrderNumber_5 <- data.frame(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
OrderType_1 <- data.frame(c("ball", "pen", "ball", "shuttle", "pen"))
OrderType_2 <- data.frame(c("pen", NA, "ball", "ball", "pen"))
OrderType_3 <- data.frame(c("shuttle", NA, NA, NA, NA))
OrderType_4 <- data.frame(c("pen", NA, NA, NA, NA))
OrderType_5 <- data.frame(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
report_output <- cbind(custID, OrderNumber_1, OrderNumber_2, OrderNumber_3, OrderNumber_4, OrderNumber_5, OrderType_1, OrderType_2, OrderType_3, OrderType_4, OrderType_5 )

report_output <-as.data.frame(report_output)
```

As you can see the shift in the values after removing "cap"  in both the column - Order_Number & Order_Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `apply`

```
report[7:ncol(report)] <-  t(apply(report[7:ncol(report)], 1, function(x) {
               i1 <- x == 'cap'
              c(x[!i1], rep(NA, sum(i1, na.rm = TRUE)))}))
report
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6      V7   V8      V9  V10  V11
#1  1  1  2  3  4  5    ball  pen shuttle  pen <NA>
#2  2  1 NA NA NA NA     pen <NA>    <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3  3  1  2  3  4  5    ball ball    <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4  4  1  2  3  4  5 shuttle ball    <NA> <NA> <NA>
#5  5  1  2 NA NA NA     pen  pen    <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

-checking with the expected

```
report_output
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6      V7   V8      V9  V10 V11
#1  1  1  2  3  4 NA    ball  pen shuttle  pen  NA
#2  2  1 NA NA NA NA     pen <NA>    <NA> <NA>  NA
#3  3  1  2 NA NA NA    ball ball    <NA> <NA>  NA
#4  4  1  2 NA NA NA shuttle ball    <NA> <NA>  NA
#5  5  1  2 NA NA NA     pen  pen    <NA> <NA>  NA
```

#### data

```
names(report) <- paste0('V', seq_along(report))
names(report_output) <- paste0('V', seq_along(report_output))
```

Comment: can the same code be used if we have more columns on the right of the data frame? I will definitely change the range of columns.

Comment: just change the index `7:ncol(report)`. here i specified from 7th column to end. if u need say from 4th change it to 4:ncol(report). or selectin 4 to 6 8 to 10 `c(4:6, 8:10)`

Comment: this worked perfectly fine. Thank you. Also, if there are columns on the right hand side containing time values, like the example you helped in yesterday, how can I change those values corresponding to "cap". Like we changed the values in the OrderNumber Columns in the above example?

Comment: Suppose, there are columns containing "Time Values" for each order number/order type. I want to remove the time value of "Cap" and replace it with the next or subsequent time value of other order type. Ill tag this question in my previous post.

Comment: Let me check your previous post

Comment: @AashayMehta  In that case, you can subset the time columns with `grep` (more dynamic. `nm1 <- grep("^time\\d+$", names(report), value = TRUE); report[nm1] <- t(apply(report[nm1], 1, function(x) { i1 <- x == 'cap' c(x[!i1], rep(NA, sum(i1, na.rm = TRUE)))}))`